# Could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell after going back from background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, custom-keyboard

I'm building a Keyboard extension in Swift3.

First time my keyboard is launch, no issue, my collection view is displayed juste fine, everything works.

This bug occurs when my keyboard goes to background and go back again in foreground. For example, I launch iMessage, display my keyboard, tap on the "home button" of my iPhone, launch iMessage again -> crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier KeyboardViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Here is how I set my storyboard for my cell identifier:

[image: Cell identifier]

With the right class:

[image: Cell class]

And here is how I call it from the `cellForItemAt indexPath` method:

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! KeyboardViewCell
        return cell
```

I don't understand why this crash after changing keyboards, like there is no storyboard loaded in that case or something...Did I forgot something?

My storyboard is like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `KeyboardViewController` holds two `UICollectionView`s. Make sure `MyCollectionView` is calling its `dataSource` when dequeueing the `KeyboardViewCell` in cellForItemAt indexPath:

```
if collectionView === myCollectionView {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! KeyboardViewCell
    return cell
} else {
    //dequeue soundCollectionViewCell
}
```

If you are conforming to the same protocol for more than one "delegator" (i.e. more than one ColletionView), you have to implement this check in every callback method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a good idea but it's not working, because it always goes to the "else"

Comment: That is another issue which you are able to debug now.

Comment: For those who come with the same problem, don't forget to add this check in your numberOfItemsInSection too !